# iPhone/iPod position fixed

Tags: iphone, scroll, position, mobile-safari, css-position

I wrote some code similiar to the code shown in this [tutorial](http://functionsource.com/post/ios5-positionfixed-overlayscroll) under the topic .iOS5 { position:fixed; overlay:scroll }.

Is there a way to prevent from the behaviour (second 8/9 of the video) in scrolling down to a grey background? I just want the user to scroll in my page and if he reaches the end there shall not be a grey background.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's part of the native interface. You _may_ be able to stop it by simply stopping the user from scrolling. Something like `document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }` and do that when the user has moved to the topmost or bottommost. But it's just a thought.

Comment: Very nice thought. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this.

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?673175-iphone-gt-safari-gt-Lock-viewport-scrolling